# How can I get categories on all views in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I have navbar.blade.php in inc forlder. I have included navbar in layout of the app. The navbar is showing in multiple pages. I want to display category dropdown on navbar. I get error of undefined variable categories.

This is categories controller

```
public function index()
    {
        $categories = Category::all();
        return view('inc.navbar')->with('categories', $categories);
    }
```

Navbar blade view

```
@if($categories)
  @foreach ($categories as $category)
    <a href="" class="dropdown-item">{{$category->name}}</a>
  @endforeach
@endif
```

Although product index page works fine and show all the categories.

Comment: Take a look at the documentation; there is specifically a section for how to share data with all views: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/views#sharing-data-with-all-views

Comment: Also, read about View Composers. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/views#view-composers

Comment: @TimLewis I tried that before but I couldn't solved

Comment: @TimLewis Thank you, this solved the problem

Answer (score 3):

You can use a View Share if you want to share this data with **all** possible views when rendered. You can use a View Composer if you want to pass data to this specific view when it is rendered.

View Composer example:

```
View::composer('inc.navbar', function ($view) { 
    $view->with('categories', Category::all());
});
```

You can put this in any Service Provider's `boot` method to register this View Composer.

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Views - View Composers](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/views#view-composers) `View::composer`

Comment: I added in AppServiceProvider but I was getting "Class 'App\Providers\View' not found", I added "use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;" at top of AppServiceProvider, again I am getting the undefined variable error

Comment: because that was an example of the view name, you have to adjust that if it is in a folder (I adjusted for your 'inc' directory)... the class not found is just a PHP error because of namespacing

Comment: @Ihtisham I think you don't understand, then  just put  one line in the `boot function` as 
    `View::share('categories', Category::all());` then you can access it from any blade with `$categories`

Comment: @lagbox I used View::share and it worked. Thank you so much